# Is it unusual to add "el" to "(El) que... no quiere decir que" to say "Just because... doesn't mean that"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, conjunciones, artículos

> **Que**... subjunctive... no quiere decir que... subjunctive...

I think this is the standard phrase, but is it unusual to place the definite article "el" at the beginning?

> **El que**... subjunctive... no quiere decir que... subjunctive...

I mean, in the same manner as saying, for instance:

> **El que** quiera estar con su madre es natural.

---

By the way, do the following two work just as well to say "Just because... doesn't mean that"?

> **Solo porque**... subjunctive... no quiere decir que... subjunctive...
>
> **El hecho de que**... subjunctive... no quiere decir que... subjunctive...

Comment: I think you need to post a full sentence. But you may be after a lo and not an el.

Comment: I agree with @Lambie You should expand your question with full examples. I also think you may be after a "lo" like in **"...lo que no quiere decir que..."**

Comment: I can see why you combined these into one question -- but your two questions are sort of on the cusp of what comfortably fits into one question, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The article about [***que***](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW) in the DPD explains this exact case:

> 2. Conjunción
>
> 2.1.1. Cuando la oración sustantiva funciona como sujeto, puede ir opcionalmente precedida del artículo *el*: *«El que hubiera una escena de amor pudo ser mera casualidad»* (GlzLeón Viejo [Ven. 1995]); *«Que el asesino hubiera usado un cuchillo era muy significativo»* (Rojo Matar [Esp. 2002]).

That is:

> When the nominal clause functions as a subject, it can optionally be preceded by the article *el*.

So it is indeed correct and quite used, specially when you want to emphasize the subject. So you would say *El que haya gente pasando hambre es algo que nos debería preocupar* when you really want to focus on the people starving.

Comment: I often think of "el que" as short hand for "el hecho de que".  Would not surprise me in the least if that's the origin, given that it otherwise overlaps with "el que…" where "el" is the object of an adjectival clause ("el que ellas escogieron" could be "that the girls chose" or "that which the girls chose").  Probably isn't, though.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, consider

> Que se separen de la mamá o el papá por la fuerza es imperdonable.

This is correct, but the reader might get off on the wrong track after "Que se separen de la mamá o el papá por la fuerza," because without "es imperdonable," it would mean

> They should be separated from their parents.  (Literally: May they be separated....)

I think this is why the optional article is usually included.  It eliminates the ambiguity.

For your second question, here are some common ways to express "Just because... doesn't mean that...":

> El que Juan diga que Mari es bonita no quiere decir que tú no lo seas también.
>
> El solo hecho de haber atacado otro país no anula los tratados internacionales sobre el trato humano de los prisioneros de guerra.
>
> Tener título no te da el derecho de despreciar a los demás.

Your first idea, "solo porque" doesn't work, as far as I know.  Your second idea, "el hecho de que" does work.  You can vary it by omitting "hecho de que", and you can make it clearer and stronger by putting "solo" in front of "hecho."

Comment: Good point about the fact that "Que se separen..." without the final verb means something completely different, as it sounds as "Let's have this done!"